# PHP regex to identify specific URL patterns

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to identify URL patterns of a page. For which I followed the below but have ended up with a issue

-> PHP regex used :

```
~((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)~i
```

This has identified almost all types of URL's like below

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com    
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
```

But unfortunately it also considered Decimal values, Price values, Phone no.s, IP address as URL format (may be I have not considered them earlier). So to fix this I have used to below to find specific numeric valued patterns to be excluded

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,})+\S+\w?$/
```

Using this has fixed the URL identifier by excluding numeric values like

Deciaml Values (1.11)

IP Address (123.123.123.123)

Price values ($11.11)

Now comes the new issue "Abbreviations are also considered as URLs"

W.H.O (in any alphabetical case)

So, How can I have an URL Identifying PHP regex which would exclude the above mentioned issue cases ?

or

Can I have an PHP regex to identify single alphabet values involving Abbreviations like the above example ?

Thanks

Comment: You should not post links to bogus URLs. That's code so you must format it as such (it's the `{}` toolbar button):

Comment: Pardon me for typos :)

Comment: Try [`'~\b(?![A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])+\b|\d+(?:\.\d+)+\S+\b)((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w.]+)+\w(?::\d+)?(/([-\w/_.]*(?:\?\S+)?)?)*)\b~'`](https://regex101.com/r/iuozYk/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put these exclusions into a negative lookahead and use

```
$re = '~(?x)\b                   # Word boundary
   (?!                           # Exclusion list
     [A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])+\b         # No upper and 1+ sequences of . + an upper
     |                           # or
     \d+(?:\.\d+)+\S+\b          # digits + 1+ dot and digits and 1+ non-whitespaces
   )       
   (?:https?://)?                # Optional http / https protocol part
   (?:[-\w]+\.[-\w.]+)+          # 1+ sequences of 1+ - or word chars, then . and 1+ -, ., or word chars
   \w(?::\d+)?                   # word char and 1 optional sequence of : and 1+ digits
   (?:/(?:[-\w/.]*(?:\?\S+)?)?)* # 0+ sequences of /, 0+ -, word, /, . symbols, then 1 optional sequence of ? and 1+ non-whitespaces
   \b~';                         # word boundary
$str = 'example.com  www.example.com  http://example.com http://www.example.com     https://example.com https://www.example.com  Deciaml Values (1.11)  IP Address (123.123.123.123)   W.H.O   Price values ($11.11)';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/bS786o) online, and a [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iuozYk/2).